# Filter inner lists from outer lists

Tags: list, netlogo

For example, if I have a list of lists like below, how do you identify the group of inner lists that contains all "0"?

```
[[0 0 1303] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [1303 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 1303 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 1303]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `filter` and `n-values` to check that the filtered item is not equal to a number of zeroes equal to its length:

```
to-report clean [ list_ ]
  report filter [ f -> f != n-values length f [0] ] list_
end

to check
  let all [[0 0 1303] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [1303 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 1303 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 1303]]

  print clean all

  print clean [ [ 0 ] [ 0 1 ] [ 1 0 ] [ 0 0 ] [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 ] [ 1 0 0 0 ] ]  
end
```

Output after running `check` procedure:

```
[[0 0 1303] [1303 0 0] [0 1303 0] [0 0 1303]]
[[0 1] [1 0] [1 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks Luke. That's very clever way.

Answer (score 0):

work out a solution as below. Are there any better and simple ways? (e.g. use map function)

```
let a [[0 0 1303] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [1303 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 1303 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 1303]] 
foreach a [x -> if (length filter [ i -> i > 0 ] x) = 0 [set a remove x a]] 
show a
```

Comment: So you want to remove all items from `a` that contain only 0 as in the output here?

Comment: Is this an answer, or an addendum to your question, if the last, please **edit your question** and remove this answer. Otherwise, please edit this answer so it is more clearly an answer.